# mockito when method returns null in junit

Tags: junit, mockito

I have been writing the test cases using the mockito. the below is my code in the test cases.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks    
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Mock
    private LoginController loginController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();

    }

    @Test
    public final void test() throws Exception {

        // Assign
        when(loginService.test()).thenReturn("hello");

        // act
        mockMvc.perform(get("/hello"))
                // Assertion
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Message from service: hello"));
        verify(loginService).test();
    }

    @Test
    public final void usernameInvalidAndPassword() throws Exception {

        User userData = new User();
        userData.setUserName("akhila.s@cloudium.io");
        userData.setPassword("Passw0rd");


        User userDataNew = new User();
        userDataNew.setUserName("akhila.s@cloudium.io");
        userDataNew.setPassword("Passw0rd");


        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();

        requestBody.put("userName", "akhila.s@cloudium.io");
        requestBody.put("password", "Passw0rd");

        JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject();

        responseBody.put("status_code", "200");
        responseBody.put("message", "ok");

        // Assign
        when(loginService.saveUser(userData)).thenReturn(userDataNew);

        // act
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")
                .param("userName", "akhila.s@cloudium.io")
                .param("password", "Passw0rd"))
                // Assertion
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().json(responseBody.toString())).andDo(print());
    }
```

For the first test case its working fine but for the second test it is returning null always. Can anyone  please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have the annotations the wrong way round on your LoginController and LoginService.  You are testing the controller so you don't want to mock it, and you are stubbing methods on your service so this needs to be a mock:

```
 @Mock  
 private LoginService loginService;

 @InjectMocks
 private LoginController loginController;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have to either:

**1)** Introduce equals method based on `username` and `password` as the User object created inside the method under test is a different instance than the one you create and use in the test.

**2)** Use a wildcard in your set-up:

```
when(loginService.saveUser(Mockito.any(User.class))).thenReturn(userDataNew);
```